# Check if superview is UITableViewController UIViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, superview

I have a custom class I created. Is there a way to check if it's `superview` is a `UITableViewController`, or a `UIViewController?

Comment: Do you mean its parentViewController? Or its superclass?

Comment: I have a custom class that subclasses UITextField. I want to check in that class if it's parent view, (self.superview) is a UITableViewController, or a UIViewController. Sorry I'm a newbie, but what is the diff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access nextResponder property of your superview

> [self.view.superview nextResponder];

or if in custom class

> [self.superview nextResponder];

and check throw isKindOfClass if this is the view controller type you're looking for.

Apple's documentation of -[UIResponder nextResponder]:

> UIView implements this method by returning the UIViewController object
>   that manages it (if it has one) or its superview (if it doesn’t)

Comment: I tried: `if ([self.superview.nextResponder isKindOfClass:[UITableViewController class]]) NSLog(@"tableVC"); and I made the else if to viewController. I didn't get any responses from both of them

Comment: this only will work if your custom class has already been  added to superview, in other case superview is nil

Comment: this snippet works if ( [[self.superview nextResponder] isKindOfClass:[UIViewController class]])
    {
        NSLog(@"");
    }

Comment: Just found out the problem! So I made an nslog of self.superview.nextResponder. When it's a viewController, I get viewController. When it's a tableViewController, I get UITableViewCell. So now how can I check if it's a tableViewcontroller?

Comment: as i know, uitableviewcell can not exist out of uitableview, so you can check your clause by uitableviewcell class. to get uitableviewcontroller from uitableviewcell - you may use the same way